# Individual-level parameter estimates from ordered choice regressions

Tags: r, regression-coefficients, logit, probit, bayes

I have got a question regarding ordered choice regressions in **R**.

I have several demographic variables with which I want to explain the ordered choice of individuals within a survey in an **ordered choice** (**probit** or **logit**, this is not important) framework. Standard ordered choice estimations of course just give me aggregate parameter estimates. For my task it would however be useful to estimate or extract "hypothetical" individual-level parameter estimates (betas) for a certain independent variable and each individual in the survey.

I have experimented with hierarchical Bayes algorithms provided by the **bayesm** and **ChoiceModelR**. Correct me if I am wrong but I think these techniques also demand that individuals appear several times within a survey and are confronted with different choice situations, so that one can estimate the influence of certain attributes on the individuals choices.

My data however don't have any panel structure. I was also experimenting with Bayesian inference in example by the **MCMCoprobit** function in the **MCMCpack** package, but this function just simulates betas. I can't however, as far as I know, attribute them to certain individuals in the survey, which would be good. I would be very glad if somebody could give me a hint, sometimes already a catchword is helpful to google the correct solution!

Comment: Cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870427/individual-level-parameter-estimates-from-ordered-choice-regressions

Comment: @BrandonBertelsen yes this is why i asked - should i delete the question on stackoverflow?

Comment: When you're asking about statistical method, or availability of a statistical method in a packaged format, the place to ask is CV. If you have problems programming your analysis (or using a package), that's when you would bring the question to stackoverflow.

Comment: i got it yeah - it is kind of a mixed problem, thus my question should the question on stackoverflow be deleted?

Comment: See: http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq with emphasis on the programming section.

Comment: hello, isn't there anybody out there who could help me? is there a way to push this thread upwards?